# URL validation regex allows one case I'd like to disallow

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Here is my regex:

```
^(?#Protocol)((ht)tp(s?)\:\/\/|~\/|\/){1}((?#IP Address)(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|(?#Subdomains)(([-\w]+\.)+(?#TopLevel Domains))([a-z]+))(?#Port)(:[\d]{1,5})?(\/\S*)*$
```

It allows this URL, but I'd like it to disallow `http://10.10.10.10.comasdf`.

Can anyone help me understand where it is wrong?

```
BTW, the following URLs are (correctly) allowed by the regex:

http://www.google.com
http://google.com
http://www.google.COM
http://google.co
http://www.google.c
http://www.google.biz
http://www.google.edu
http://android.google.com
http://www.google.com.asdf
http://android.google.com.jp
http://www.google.michael
http://www.mysite10.com
http://10mysite.com
http://209.85.148.103
http://209.85.148.103:8080
http://www.google.com:8080
http://www.google.japan
http://209.85.148.103/asdf
http://www.google.japan/asdf
http://www.google.japan/asdf/xcvb
http://209.85.148.103/asdf/xcvb
http://www.google.japan/asdf10/xcvb
http://209.85.148.103/asdf10/xcvb
http://www.google.japan/asdf10/xcvb30grts
http://209.85.148.103/asdf10/xcvb30grts
http://209.85.148.103/asdf10#xcvb30grts
http://www.google.japan/asdf10#xcvb30grts
```

Answer (score 0):

When you ip address doesn't match, it tries to match the `|` condition. And it successfully does because `10.10.10.10.comasdf` matches `([-\w]+\.)+([a-z]+)`

Try puting a `?>` before the `(?#IP Address)`. That way, when the ip address does match, it won't attempt the `|(?#Subdomains)(([-\w]+\.)+(?#TopLevel Domains))([a-z]+)` after failing the `(?#Port)(:[\d]{1,5})?(\/\S*)*$`

```
^(?#Protocol)((ht)tp(s?)\:\/\/|~\/|\/){1}(?>(?#IP Address)(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|(?#Subdomains)(([-\w]+\.)+(?#TopLevel Domains))([a-z]+))(?#Port)(:[\d]{1,5})?(\/\S*)*$
```

See: http://regexr.com?2u8ks

Comment: This assumes the OP is using a flavor that supports `(?>atomic groups)` as well as `(?#inline comments)`.  Most flavors support both features or neither; however, Python supports inline comments but not atomic groups.  (Java goes the other way: atomic groups but not inline comments.)

Comment: His example has inline comments, so I'm assuming that it supports that. Good point about atomic groups.

Comment: Your suggestion to try putting a ?> before the (?#IP Address) worked perfectly, thanks!